# Problema con JsonArrayRequest

Tags: android-studio, json

Estoy trabajando con JsonArrayRequest para poder recuperar datos desde un webservice pero me da un error a la hora de ejecutar, este es el error que me da:

> Error:(62, 45) error: no suitable constructor found for
>   JsonArrayRequest(int,String,>,) constructor
>   JsonArrayRequest.JsonArrayRequest(String,Listener,ErrorListener)
>   is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   constructor
>   JsonArrayRequest.JsonArrayRequest(int,String,JSONArray,Listener,ErrorListener)
>   is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Aqui esta la clase que donde implemento el JsonArrayRequest:

```
package com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.adapter.Usuario;
import com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.adapter.UsuarioAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Enriq on 26/04/2018.
 */

public class asignaturaFragmento extends Fragment {
    private String url = "http://192.168.1.70:8080/WebService/webapi/usuarios";
    private ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();

    public asignaturaFragmento() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_prueba, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2,
                GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        final UsuarioAdapter adapter = new UsuarioAdapter(getActivity(), usuarios);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Por favor espere...");
        dialog.show();

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        deserializarJSONArray(response);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if (dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error al realizar la petición \n" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        return view;
    }

    public void deserializarJSONArray(JSONArray jsonArray) {

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Usuario tarea = new Usuario();
                tarea.setId(item.getString("id"));
                tarea.setContrasena(item.getString("contrasena"));
                tarea.setNombreUsuario(item.getString("nombreUsuario"));

                usuarios.add(tarea);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error al procesar la respuesta de la petición tarea",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Esta es mi clase adptador para obtener los valores del Json:

```
package com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Next University.
 */
public class UsuarioAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsuarioAdapter.UsuarioHolder>{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios;

    public UsuarioAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.usuarios = usuarios;
    }

    protected class UsuarioHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView txtId, txtNombreUsuario, txtContrasena;

        public UsuarioHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
            txtNombreUsuario = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre_usuario);
            txtContrasena = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_contrasena);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public UsuarioHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.plantilla_usuario, parent, false);
        UsuarioHolder holder = new UsuarioHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UsuarioHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtId.setText(usuarios.get(position).getId());
        holder.txtNombreUsuario.setText(usuarios.get(position).getNombreUsuario());
        holder.txtContrasena.setText(usuarios.get(position).getContrasena());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return usuarios.size();
    }
}
```

**No me muestra el error en la clase, solamente cuando ejecuto mi aplicacion me sale el error.**

Comment: Puedes agregar el json a la pregunta porque el error eso indica que esta mal contruido

Comment: @RaulCacacho pues el Json lo creo de esta forma JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

Comment: yo me refiero al json que recibes

Comment: @RaulCacacho ya agregue la clase donde tengo mi adaptador para la informacion que recibo de la consulta